# How to modify the HTML of blocks ex- Newsletter Block, Popular Tags block in Magento

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I would like to modify the HTML of the default magento blocks, so that I can change there tags and classes.

Please see the image here to know the blocks I want to edit.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq6b7.png

Please let me know the file path, or process of doing this.

Comment: Not sure, why this question was closed, however the Answer given by  Dushyant Joshi is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the following templates.

```
magento/app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/tag/

magento/app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml
```